# Multisim. Why the parameters of voltage in osciloscope and voltmeter diferent?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope, multisim

I have simple design:

[image]

and the oscilloscope graphic:
[image]

The Voltage of oscilloscope and voltmeter mismatches.
The oscilloscope value is higher.
Why and how can I fix it? I'm using Multisim 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oscilloscope is displaying the 100 \$V_{rms}\$ waveform exactly as it is, \$141 V_{pk}\$. (For the sine wave case, the peak value is \$\sqrt{2}*V_{rms}\$.) The meter is displaying the [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) voltage, which you put in the simulation. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: is there any way to configure oscilloscope to show in Vrms? or I need all the time multiply it with 2^0.5? how the engineers do?

Comment: Real scopes have RMS as a measurement function, along with a ton of other parameters. For simulation purposes, use measurement probes when you need values, instead of the test equipment blocks. (Not sure where they are in Multisim 13, check the help files.)